# ActiveMQ Artemis DLQ queue assignment

Tags: activemq-artemis

Using Artemis 2.31.2, I am creating multiple queues (queue1 .. queue8) in the consumer using:

```java
session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
session.createConsumer(session.createQueue(queueName));
```

In `broker.xml` I have this configuration which assigns dead letters to individual `queueName.DLQ` on `session.rollback()`

```xml
<dead-letter-address>DLA</dead-letter-address>
<max-delivery-attempts>2</max-delivery-attempts>
<auto-create-dead-letter-resources>true</auto-create-dead-letter-resources>
<dead-letter-queue-prefix></dead-letter-queue-prefix> <!-- override the default -->
<dead-letter-queue-suffix>.DLQ</dead-letter-queue-suffix>
```

I attempt to process the message and rollback on failure.

```java
try{ "process message..." }  
catch (Exception e) {   
  try {     
     session.rollback();   
  } catch (JMSException ex) {   
    LOGGER.info("JMSException in session rollback: {}", ex.getMessage());   
  }   
  LOGGER.error("Exception in queue: {} e: {}", queueName, e); 
}
```

which works fine as long as I do not `setMessageListener` on the `queueName.DLQ` but when I set `setMessageListener` on the `queueName.DLQ`, DLQ messages are assigned to random `queueName.DLQ`, not the `queueName` which the rollback happened 2 times.
For example message rolled back from queue1 gets copied to queue5.DLQ, next time it gets copied to queue3.DLQ, etc...

```java
session.createConsumer(session.createQueue("DLA::" + queueName + ".DLQ")).setMessageListener(message -> {
  try {
    LOGGER.info("DLQ msg in queue: {}", queueName);
    message.acknowledge();
  } catch (JMSException e) {
    LOGGER.info("JMSException acknowledging a DLQ message: {}", e.getMessage());
  }
});
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are creating the `MessageConsumer` on the DLQ (e.g. `DLA::queue1.DLQ`) and setting the `MessageListener` **before** `rollback` is invoked. If that's the case then that means the creation of the consumer is triggering the creation of the DLQ rather than the broker creating it automatically based on `<auto-create-dead-letter-resources>true</auto-create-dead-letter-resources>`. This circumvents a *very important* step which the broker would normally execute - setting the filter on the dead letter queue. This is noted in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/undelivered-messages.html#automatically-creating-dead-letter-resources) which states:

> The `address` created will be the one defined by the `dead-letter-address`. A `MULTICAST` `queue` will be created on that `address`. It will be named by the `address` to which the message was previously sent, and **it will have a filter defined using the property `_AMQ_ORIG_ADDRESS` so that it will only receive messages sent to the relevant `address`**.

Since this step is not executed in your case every queue on the dead-letter address will receive *every* message instead of just the ones that it should.

You should allow the broker to automatically create the dead-letter resources itself without interference from your application or you should statically configure them as needed and disable auto-creation.

Comment: How do I add a `setMessageListener` on each .DLQ then? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should either wait until the broker has automatically created the dead-letter resources itself or you should statically configure them as needed and disable auto-creation.

Comment: I am fine with using just one DLQ but when add `setMessageListener` to it, messages do not appear there. I was hoping to use just one DLQ and filter them by `ORIG-ADDRESS`

Comment: I recommend you ask a new question about this specific issue.

Comment: Also, if you're using the latest version of ActiveMQ Artemis then you should be using the [latest documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/) as well. The documentation link in your previous comment is from 1.4.0, not 2.31.2.